# JMeter | How to introduce double quotes while parameterizing via CSV Data Set Config

Tags: csv, automation, jmeter, load-testing

While parameterizing a WebService using CSV Data Set Config. I need to include double quotes (“) for a parameter (as an acceptable format of a value).
Had tried with applying quotes in the request and from the file and even using the Tab as delimiter, but still the script is failing with same reason as below:-

Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

We are trying to test a WebService request with multiple set of data, the XML/body is updated with the ${name} for the parameters.

```
<ABC msgid=${MSG_ID} msgtime="2016-02-08 14:51:23.741" tranid=${MSG_ID}     xmlns="http://www.google.com">
<Sender vendor="XYZ">
  <Application name="RRR" version="3" />
  <Machine name="RRRSERVER" />
</Sender>
<Door name="1" />
<Location name=${LOCATION} latitude="0" longitude="0" />
```

In above request the ${MSG_ID}'s value should be in double quotes (like "123321"), tried with adding those in the CSV file and in the message body and also tried with adding '"' in the body. However the scripts is still failing and JMeter's listner shows the above error.

The expected outcome should be msgid="123321" msgtime="2016-02-08 14:51:23.741" tranid="12345678"

Please share any inputs on this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you are adding double quotes? The first sentence of the question has an 0xE2 between the brackets, not an 0x22. Below the code block there is `adding '&quot;' in the body` but the `&quot;` is displayed as a quote.

Answer (score 3):

First of all try it with hard-coded values. If it works - just add the quotation marks to your XML payload like:

```
<ABC msgid="${MSG_ID}"
```

Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details.

If not - the reason of failure can be different. For instance you may have to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header with the value of `application/xml` or `text/xml` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me after adding content-type as application/json and double quotes around variable name like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Quotes]

If you're looking for a way to send quoted values in your HTTP request as a part of XML body, then check the picture below. Jmeter correctly understands regular quotes defined in raw body. So, just use your parameters in a similar way. Is it the case?

Comment: Please include the significant details from that image in the answer. That image is on another website and it might be removed making this answer useless. For a better explanation please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Thanks for your note, Adrian. Will take it into account as I use screenshots rather often. I'll be more attentive next time.